# How to Add PNG Image as Button Image in CMFCToolBar?

Tags: image-processing, mfc, cbitmap, cmfctoolbar

Seems like CMFCToolBar Allowing only BITMAP Images ( which are of color depth 24 ) to place on Buttons. How to get rid of this limitation. i am neither able to place a PNG nor a bit map with color depth 32 (alpha channel included).

i tried attaching my CPngImage to CBitmap but didn't work.

```
CPngImage image;
image.Load(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), IDB_PNG1);
bitmap.Attach(image.Detach());
```

so, finally my doubt can we add a PNG/ Bitmap with alpha channel to CMFCToolBar Button as Image?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work: [Icons on menus of MFC Feature Pack classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386/icons-on-menus-of-mfc-feature-pack-classes) ? You'd probably have to adapt it a bit to get it to work in your specific case. I'd suggest staying away from using PNG for toolbar icons etc; you can use AlphaConv (google a bit to find it - it moves around a bit it seems) to convert from png to 32 bit bmp.